# Vagrant won't run nosetests under ssh -c

Tags: python, vagrant, nose, nosetests

I wanted to write a command to ssh into vagrant, change the current working directory, and then run nosetests.

I found in the documentation for vagrant that this could be done with `vagrant ssh -c COMMAND`

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh.html

The problem is I'm getting different results if I run nose through -c or manually after SSH.

Command:

`vagrant ssh -c 'pwd && cd core && pwd && nosetests -x --failed' web`

Output:

```
/web
/web/core

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 4.784s

OK
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

Commands:

`vagrant ssh web`

`/web$ pwd && cd core && pwd && nosetests -x --failed`

Output

```
/web                                                     
/web/core                                                
.........................................................
.........................................................
.........................................................
.........................................................
<snip>
...............................                          
---------------------------------------------------------

Ran 1399 tests in 180.325s
```

I don't understand why it makes a difference.

Comment: i believe "vagrant ssh" would run in login mode as a result profile file would be run and "vagrant ssh -c" is not a login shell so profile would not be invoked and. i guess the enviroment for the test  is not the same and requires setup via source profile file.  you can check it out  with `vagrant ssh -c 'shopt' web` , i haven't had a chance to test it will update once i do.

Comment: I tried `vagrant ssh -c 'shopt' web`, but I don't know what I'm looking for.

This is what I thought may be relevant:

    login_shell - on
    restricted_shell - off
    sourcepath - on
    hostcomplete - on

Answer (score 1):

The first ssh session is not a terminal session. If you try `ssh -t` instead of `vagrant ssh -c`, likely the outputs will be the same. A command like the following should give output comparable to what you get locally:

`ssh -t <username>@<ip-of-vagrant-machine> -p <vagrant-vm-ssh-port> 'pwd && cd core && pwd && nosetests -x --failed'`

The default for username and password on vagrant machines is both "vagrant", the ssh-port and IP to ssh into are shown during the provisioning of the vagrant machine with `vagrant up`. If you prefer public key ssh login vagrant also can point you to the location of the ssh public key.

Depending on where you want to run nose on your vm you will have to adjust the `cd` command above, it seems that the vagrant ssh wrapper automatically moved you to `/web` on the VM.

If you just worry about wether the results of the tests will differ because of the visual difference: No, they shouldn't, the reason is just that on a non-interactive terminal nose displays the results in a different manner.

Comment: I don't have -t available as an option. What version of vagrant are you running, and could you please show an example command?

Comment: You will likely have to run the ssh client manually instead of through vagrant. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by running:

`vagrant ssh -c 'cd core && nosetests -x --failed --exe' web`

I'm not sure why this made a difference on my box.